# How do I use multiple bibliography styles

Tags: bibliographies

e.g. I want to use bibliographystyle{unsrt} to do the referencing as per order of appearance along with bibliographystyle{abbrv} to abbreviate the names of the autho. Is this possible?

Comment: no, only one style at a time. You will basically have to find a style that merge the two.

Comment: I would write more precisely: `\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none, firstinits=true]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Maybe some fine-tuning will be necessary (e.g.  order first name-last name or last-first, punctuation, &c.). What are the details of the `abbrev` bibliography style?